# how to make high quality icons in low ppi?

Tags: vector, icons, photoshop

I'm trying to make icons for my app's navigation drawer and dashboard but the problem is whenever I try to decrease the size or pixels per inch value of the icons they get pixelated. I tried to redraw them with the pen tool in order to make vectors but the problem lingered. Is there any way to ease around this obstacle?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just make icons in 72 ppi?
There is no way to make high quality icons in low ppi